# pointer-event - none is not working when I use tab key

Tags: html, css

I am making a form where I am using a Class to disabled my inputs using pointer-even: none, my input is not editable when I am trying to click on the input which is correct, but when I am using "TAB" key it is focusing on input and I can edit the input, how i can prevent focus should not go on my input using tab key, and should allow to edit the input.

```
<form style="padding:10px; margin:10px" action="" class=" form-inline">
          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="input-group">
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="input-group">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control disabledClass" placeholder="1">
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <div class="input-group">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control disabledClass" placeholder="2" >
                </div>
              </div>

            </div>
          </div>
        </form>

CSS:
.disabledClass{
  background: #f1f1f1;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

your early reply appreciated..

Comment: Why not use the [`disabled`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#disabled) attribute on the input? You could also set tabIndex to -1.

Comment: I want to handle it through class only, I dont want to use disabled attribute..

Comment: It not possible just only css. The Mozilla doc says "Elements with pointer-events: none will still receive focus through sequential keyboard navigation using the Tab key."

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/q/73428922/2010598

Answer (score 7):

`pointer-events` CSS rules only affects pointer events (think of mouse-events, even though there are other pointer-events).
Navigating through keyboard is not part of the pointer events.

There were some CSS rules that were supposed to help in your situation, but none seems to properly work, and they aren't standardized anyway.

For instance, I would have thought that the non standard [`-moz-user-focus`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-moz-user-focus) (only in FF) would have done this, but it doesn't. [`user-select`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/user-select) or non-standard [`user-modify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/user-modify) do not prevent it either.
The only way I found is actually though HTML, by setting both the `readonly` and the `tabindex="-1"` attributes (`disabled` would also do, but generally comes with some dimmed styling):

```css
input {
  pointer-events: none;
}
.no-focus {
  -moz-user-focus: none;
  -webkit-user-focus: none;
  -ms-user-focus: none;
  user-focus: none;
  -moz-user-modify: read-only;
  -webkit-user-modify: read-only;
  -ms-user-modify: read-only;
  user-modify: read-only;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="no-focus" value="CSS">
<input type="text" readonly value="readonly" tabindex="-1">

<pre>First click this iframe then try to navigate using TAB</pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can additional add event keydown to the form

```
if (event.keyCode == 9) {
    event.preventDefault();
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The only way I'd had approach this is using **tabindex="-1"** attribute in the input tag and it worked perfectly.
More info about the [tabindex attribute here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/tabindex).

Also, don't forget to apply the **pointer-events: none;** CSS property to your label too. Clicking on your label otherwise enables the editing of the input.

```css
label {
    pointer-events: none;
}
```