# Is there a css equivalent of pointer-events but for keyboard events?

Tags: css, keyboard-events, readonly, pointer-events

I am trying to make readonly, but not disable, all types of form element only using css and html (i.e. no javascript).

Some things (like inputs) are easy - the `readonly` attribute on the input does it. For other things, like checkboxes and selects for example, `readonly` doesn't work. I can use css `pointer-events: none` to prevent clicking on it, but I haven't found a `keyboard-events: none` or similar that I can use to stop people getting to it with the keyboard and changing it.

I know of several ways to achieve this with javascript, but I'm hoping to find one that is javascript free.

Comment: `tabindex="-1"` attribute